# Should a dynamic help page content be stored in Database or HTML file?

Tags: dynamic, asp.net-webpages

So, I'm trying to come up with a better way to do a dynamic help module that displays a distinct help page for each page of a website. Currently there is a help.aspx that has a title and div section that is filled by methods that grab a database record. Each DB record is stored html withy the specific help content. Now, this works but it is an utter pain to maintain when, say an image, changes or the text has to be edited, you have to find and updated 1 or more DB records. I was thinking instead, I could build a single html page that basically shows/hides panels and inside each panel is the appropriate help content. As long as you follow a proper naming convention (name the panels ID to the page/content it represents) using ctrl + f will get you where you need to go and make it easier to find the content you need. What I'm curious of is would this have an impact on performance? The html page would be a fairly large file and would be hosted/ran at the server but it would also remove the need for Database calls. Would the work even be worth the benefit here or am I reinventing the wheel already in place?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic anything should be stored in the database. A truly usable web application should NEVER need code modified to change content. Hiding content is usually not a good idea, imagine if you expanded your application to 100 different pages that need their own help page. Then when someone clicks help their browser has to load 99 hidden pages to get 1 that it will show. You need to break your help page down into sections and just store the plain text in the database. I would need to know more about what language you're using as well as the architecture you're using to elaborate further but take a look below.

The need your describing is pretty much what MVC (web application architecture type) was built for.

If you're already using ASP.net and you aren't too far into your project I would consider switching to MVC. It's an architecture built specifically with dynamic page content in mind. You build different 'Views' (the V in MVC) that will dynamically build the HTML based on the content it receives from the Controller (The C in MVC) which pulls it's data from the database/Model (The M) and modifies it for the View. Also once you get into MVC  you can couple it with Razor and half of your code get's written for you. It's a wonderful thing.

http://www.asp.net/mvc